# Verb + object + infinitive. What is the logic behind choosing between to-infinitive or bare infinitive?

Tags: verbs, infinitives, bare-infinitive

For example, why

> I saw him **eat/eating** pasta.

but

> I asked him **to eat** pasta.

or

> She asked him **to leave** her.

but

> She saw him **leave** her.

I saw some articles about the topic that told you to remember the exact verbs. Moreover, another article — another set of verbs. Can someone explain to not native speakers what intuition lays behind this choice?

Comment: Verbs of the senses or perception such as _see, hear, watch, notice_ etc. plus object are always followed by the bare infinitive or _-ing form_. Other catenative verbs may be followed by the bare infinitive, the _to infinitive_ or the _-ing form_ (or sometimes two of the three). Unfortunately, there are no 'rules' that I know that can help you (to) determine this is advance.

Comment: Right. It all depends on the verb involved. Every verb has its own set of preferred, required, allowed, and forbidden constructions; it's part of the meaning of the verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy rule of thumb is that the bare infinitive can only be used with:

(1) Verbs of perception:

- I **saw** him **eat** pasta.
- I **heard** him **speak** in Italian.

(2) The verbs *let, make, have*:

- I **let** them **leave** at once.
- I **made** them **leave** at once.
- I **had** them **leave** at once.

Comment: The verb *bid* also takes a bare infinitive, as when you bid someone enter. It often sounds old-fashioned.

Comment: Another common one is _help_: _Can you help me put up this shelf?_ And then there is the question of the difference if any, between, for example, _I heard him speak Italian_ and _I heard him speaking Italian_.